# how to reach pygame display from different python script

Tags: python, pygame, display

I have 3 python scripts as:

1. main.py
2. player.py
3. ui.py

I initialise a pygame in ui.py like:

```
import pygame
import time
import tkinter

class ui:

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        pygame.font.init() 
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

I call the ui class from main.py
It starts a application window and I can manage everything from this file.

I can call player.py from main.py with subprocess.

```
 p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "player.py"])
```

in player.py I want to display image on the application window which already showed via main.py.

```
img = pygame.image.load('a.jpg')
screen.blit(img, (x,y))
pygame.display.update()
```

How can I reach the current window display? I need something in here instead of 'screen'.

Comment: The question is: Do you *really* need to run `player.py` in another process?

Answer (score 0):

Having each Python file run in a separate process is not the usual way of trying to write large(ish) projects.

Instead, you use the `import` statement so that each of your Python files can have access and use what is on the other files, and a main starting point file, that orchestrates everything.

If you do it in the ordinary way, the instance of your `ui` class that has the reference to the screen will be in a variable visible in the code that needs the display, and you can have the screen by writting `ui.screen`  .

Now, I understand you want to use `tkinter` along your game - maybe that is why you took this route of trying different processes, as tkinter's normal usage, and almost all examples around, tell you to call `tkinter.mainloop()` at some point. Indeed, if you do that in the same process where you are trying to run pygame code, the pygame will freeze, as tkinter loop won't update your mainloop.

There are two possible aproaches there:

1. you keep your pygame main loop as usual, with a `while True:`, and inside that loop put a call to the method `update()` of your main tkinter object.  Never call `tkinter.mainloop`.
2. You rewrite your pygame loop body as a function, and instead of the usual `while True:` to run that body, register a call to it with the method `.after` on your root tkinter object. Re-register this call at the end of the function body - and then, use tkinter's mainloop to run everything.

Both methods will allow you to have a single-threaded application that runs both pygame and tkinter code - and being able to simply import classes and functions from other Python modules and access their attributes where needed.